# Write this Cartesian product in math notation

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Basically I just want to replace the $\beta$th set in $\displaystyle\prod X_\alpha$ by $U_1$. How would I write the resulting Cartesian product in math notation?

Comment: Some context is missing. What is $U_1$? Over which set the index $\alpha$ is?

Comment: @Kolmin $U_1$ is a set. The index set is not given but we assume it contains $\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your index set $I$ is totally ordered, take the product with indices before $\beta$, then $U_1$, then the product with indices after $\beta$.

$$\left(\prod_{\alpha < \beta} X_\alpha \right) \times U_1 \times \left(\prod_{\alpha > \beta} X_\alpha \right)$$

If your index set isn't totally ordered, define $f: \{X_\alpha : \alpha\in I\} \to \{X_\alpha : \alpha\in I\} \cup \{U_1\}$ by

$$
f(X_\alpha) =
\begin{cases}
  X_\alpha & \text{if $\alpha \neq \beta$,} \\
  U_1 & \text{if $\alpha = \beta$}
\end{cases}.
$$

Then the product you want is $\prod_{\alpha \in I} f(X_\alpha)$.

Comment: This assumes the index set has a linear ordering, why should it have one?

Comment: I don't know what a Cartesian product would mean if the indices weren't ordered.

Comment: A cartesian product $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is, by definition, the set of functions $f$ with domain $I$ such that $(\forall i\in I)\,f(i)\in X_i$. This doesn't need any ordering on the index set $I$.

Comment: That makes sense. Each function has the union as codomain. I'd never encountered such a general definition. Thank you.

Comment: @HannaBrandsma: You can always give it an ordering. It doesn't particularly matter *what* the ordering is, just that there is one. (although you do have to take some care that you only discuss things that ultimately don't care which ordering)

Answer (score 0):

$$U_1×\prod_{\alpha\ne\beta} X_\alpha$$

Comment: But $\beta$ need not be 1, so how can we write $U_1$ as the first set?

Comment: If these cartesian products are taken as ordered (which is the most common situation), Jonathan’s answer is isomorphic to mephistolotl’s via a permutation of the index set. Often the order of the index set is irrelevant to the application, so this answer might be fine for its context. One could also define $Y_\beta=U_1$ and $Y_\alpha=X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\ne\beta$; then the cartesian product you want is $\displaystyle\prod Y_\alpha$.

Comment: @Thomas the question did not specify that the index set was ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Your set is exactly $\pi_\beta^{-1}[U_1]$, the set of points whose $\beta$-th coordinate is in $U_1$.